# How to create custom circle card view in android

Tags: android, android-cardview, material-components, material-components-android

I want to create custom circle card view by using custom class that extended card view in android.I use this card view in constraint layout and this card view height and width is match constraint (i don't set width and height exactly in xml code). How to do it?
Please help me.

Comment: You dont need to extend the cardview, you can make the cardview square and give it 50% of it's width as card corner radios

Comment: @Sujan Poudel My card view is match constraint and I do'nt know that width and heigh.

Comment: You can update the corner radius grammatically after your view has been inflated

Comment: @Sujan Poudel  Thanks. But i want create custom circle cardview, have u a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `MaterialCard` in the Material Components Library with the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute to customize the shape.
Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/card_circle"
        ..>
```

Then apply the `50%` to your `cornerSize`:

```
  <style name="card_circle">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: The best and easy way!